# unchangeable properties of new meshes

Tags: properties

i have been using blender 2.8 for a couple of months but now i am stuck with a problem. I cant alter the properties of a new mesh in object mode. i need to reduce the vertices of a sphere but the properties are kind of frozen. please help!

[image]

Comment: Suggest downloading the 2.80 release candidate. (From screenshot your version appears earlier, given the location of tools settings.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check in the *Preferences* > *System* > *Memory & Limits*, you need to activate the *Global Undo* option (but you need to recreate your object).

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works now :)